# Can't access button after load() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code witch generate for me a table:

```
$("#myTable").load("showTable.php");
```

On each table row, I have a button like this:

```
<a class="remove" id="1">Remove</a>
```

I'm trying to perform an action on click on this type of button like this:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

I do not work. I do not have any error message.

But it works like a charm, outside of the generate table.

Any reason why ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have `<a class="remove" id="1">Remove</a>` in each row, that is invalid. `id` should be always unique in HTML.

Comment: Because the elements don't exist at the time your code runs. You need to delegate the event to an element that does exist. This question gets asked numerous times a day here

Comment: @charlietfl, do you have any link?

Comment: @charlietfl I've sad "IF". So, please relax, and have Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @lolka_bolka I am very relaxed, you seem to have confused me with the person who made the comment

Comment: @lolka_bolka, you're right sorry. Merry Christmas to you.

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, then I am sorry :)

Comment: The non-unique id is an issue, but that is not related to the issue of the event handlers not working.  Some operations will not resolve correctly, so there may be other issues in the code, but the click handler will just show the id as written in the example (see the fiddle in my answer and make the ids duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign your click event when loading has completed (on callback event).

Like so:

```
$("#myTable").load("showTable.php", function(){
    $(".remove").click(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the click handler is being set at the loading of the page, it will not be attached to elements that are dynamically generated.  The following code demonstrates a way to do this without attaching individual handlers

```
<table id="theTable">
   <tr><td><a class='remove' id='1'>Remove</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a class='remove' id='2'>Remove</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a class='remove' id='3'>Remove</a></td></tr>
</table>

var nextId=4;
$("#theTable").on("click",".remove", function() {
   alert(this.id);    
   $("#theTable").append("<tr><td><a class='remove' id='" + nextId + "'>Remove</a></td></tr>");
   nextId = nextId + 1;
});
```

And [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpww5oy7/1/) demonstrating the functionality
Finally, the [docs to the .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) are helpful.